# How do I verify all the available options in a dropdown using Java and Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have  a dropdown with many values. I want to write a method where I can enter the expected text of all the dropdown values and compare it with the actual text of the all the dropdown values. If they match, then the tests passes. I am currently using webdriver and Java.

```
<select id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response" name="ctl00$cphMainContent$dq14$response">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="253">DEP900</option>
<option value="252">DEP800</option>
<option value="251">DEP700</option>
<option value="250">DEP600</option>
<option value="248">DEP400</option>
<option value="247">DEP300</option>
<option value="246">DEP200</option>
<option value="245">DEP100</option>
<option value="249">DEP500</option>
<option value="254">DEP1000</option>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
public boolean checkOptions(String[] expected){
    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMainContent_dq14_response"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElement(By.xpath(".//option"));
    int k = 0;
    for (WebElement opt : options){
        if (!opt.getText().equals(expected[k]){
            return false;
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```